# Swift Change button position with AutoLayout

Tags: swift, ios8

I have created the button programmatically in this way

```
func CreateButtonWithIndex(index:Int) {
    let widthButton = 120
    let heightButton = 80
    let line = (index / 3)
    let column = index % 3
    let newButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
    newButton.frame = CGRect(x:line*widthButton+95, y:column*heightButton+15, width:widthButton, height:heightButton)

    self.view.addSubview(newButton)
}
```

Now trying to place NSLayoutConstraint for this button in this way

```
func CreateButtonWithIndex(index:Int) {

    let widthButton = 120
    let heightButton = 80
    let line = (index / 3)
    let column = index % 3
    let newButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
    newButton.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

    self.view.addSubview(newButton)

    let constraint1 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newButton, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 1)

    let constraint2 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newButton, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)

    view.addConstraints([constraint1,constraint2])
```

}

but obviously i get only that the various buttons are created in the same location.
i have tried e.g.

```
   let constraint1 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newButton, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: line)
```

But don't go !!!

how can I place the line and column with the NSLayoutConstraint ?

Comment: "But don't go" is not a problem statement. Next time, please try to be specific about your question and about what problem you are encountering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track! The problem is that your calculation is not giving a big enough difference in the x positions. You are saying:

```
let constraint1 = NSLayoutConstraint(
    item: newButton, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, 
    toItem: view, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: line)
```

But what is `line`?

```
let line = (index / 3)
```

Well, if `index` is 0, then 1, then 2, `line` is going to 0 every time. You need a *much* bigger difference if you want these buttons to be in different places!

(You should also declare or cast `line` to a CGFloat, obviously.)

Comment: but if i insert let constraint1 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newButton, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: line) i have a error on line

Comment: It might help you to look at some example code that does the kind of thing you are doing. Look at this example from my book: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch07p360scrollViewInCode/ch20p570scrollViewInCode/ViewController.swift Here we are making 30 labels, each one positioned below the previous one.

Comment: could non find member CenterX

Comment: You just have to say `CGFloat(line)`, that is easy and is not the issue here. Try to concentrate on the real problem. :)

Comment: I have answered the question you asked and I believe I have answered it correctly.